# How to dissolve PLA/PCL/PMMA?

Tags: solutions, synthesis, polymers, reference-request, plastics

I have a research about electrospun membrane synthesis where I dissolve PLA pellets in chloroform:methanol (3:1) for 3 hours and also PCL pellets in chloroform:methanol (3:1) for 3 hours too. Another thing is I also dissolve PMMA powder in acetone for 15 minutes before the texture hardened. After that, I have to blend all of those solutions together to become homogenous solution.

The question is: Actually, I've tried to mix those 3 solutions with steps I tried to mix PLA and PCL first for 3 hours and then I mix it with PMMA for another 3 hours. I am wondering, is there any other steps to mix all of them efficiently (or with shorter time)?

If you could refer your answer with journals, I'd be glad to read it too. Thank you in any advance.

Comment: Its your own job to do your literature research. And you are asking too many questions at the same time. Lastly, you dont "dissolve for fifteen minutes". You can stir the mixture for fifteen minutes in the hope that it dissolves.

Comment: noted with thanks. I already changed it with just 1 question.

Comment: This question is extremely unclear (both missing facts and unclear wording) and therefore impossible to answer. You need to give quantities and concentrations, and report your observations. And please check how the word "to dissolve" is used in English language, because you are using it wrongly. Makes no sense.